# How to run snowball-io.io on Windows 10

Tags: snowball-io

I opened the snowball-io.io website and when I clicked "Play", this error message popped up. I'm just wondering how to fix this problem (without using apps that connect ios/android to computer).

[image: Snowball]

Answer (score 2):

This is a coding issue on their end. They didn't include the necessary javascript scripts. There's nothing you can do except contact support and have them update the code on the website.